# How to merge two Windows servers?

Tags: migration, windows-server-2019

I have to merge two Windows Servers, one is the old one and another is the new one which.

Both servers was working together but the new one started to work month later, on the new server i have the all clients DBs but even in the old server there are same DBs with data user for other applications hosted on old server, then i need to move the DNS from the old server to the new one.

Which would be the best way to do so without turning off the old server for lot of time?

Is the only way to turn off the old server, pass the DNS to the new one, copy the web applications from old server to new one and merge all DBs?

I need to turn the old server off in any way as the clients DBs are populated every minute so if it will be on and i will back-up clients DB it will cause loss of some datas..

Comment: Hi, if we talk DB, it can be an option to ask on DBA.stack. Generally speaking, isolate old server, create DB dump, import in new server and close the old server.

Comment: @yagmoth555 while how should i behave with DNS? as it have propagation time if i will swape it from old server to new before the DB is dumped the website will be unreachable..

Comment: It depend, it resolve to an IP behind  firewall you control or not ? in the same firewall as the new ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the databases on the old server are only used by the webapps my thought would be to get the webapps working on the new server but with the database connections pointed to the IP of the old server.
Once these are all working, swap the DNS pointer to the new server.
Now that all your clients are connecting to the new server, one at a time disable a single web app, migrate the database (backup and restore then recreate users for MSSQL) and point the webapp to the local DB before bringing it back.
Rinse and repeat for each webapp.
This would minimise downtime.